# PHP array slice multiple array non functional

Tags: php, foreach, slice

The following slices $scpar into two types one containing the first 9 and the second containing former comma separated values from 10 to 18.

```
$scpar9 = array_slice($scpar,0,9);
      $scpar18 = array_slice($scpar,9,18);
```

We then use a foreach and use an id parameter `$sid` to get the same comma separated value from other fields.

```
foreach ($scpar9 as $sid => $scpar) {
```

Information is then taken from other fields like this.

```
<b>'.$scpar.'</b> '.$sccomp[$sid].$scmen[$sid].
```

That all works fine, the problem is with the second 9 fields.

```
foreach ($scpar18 as $sid => $scpar) {
<b>'.$scpar.'</b> '.$sccomp[$sid].$scmen[$sid].
```

The field `$scpar` is correct but the ones containing the `[$sid]` are starting from the first result not the 9th.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Comment: why are you slicing these into 2 arrays? wouldn't a `for` loop be better?

Comment: Can you explain to me how that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use [preserve_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

> preserve_keys : 
>       Note that array_slice() will reorder and reset the array indices
>   by default. You can change this behaviour by setting preserve_keys to
>   TRUE.

```
   $scpar18 = array_slice($scpar,9,18, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array-slice) creates new arrays containing the *values* from the original arrays, not the keys. Using the keys in the `foreach` loop is meaningless in the context of the original array, since these are the keys from the new slice arrays.

Use `array_slice($scpar, 9, 18, true)` to copy the keys as well, not just the values:

```
$scpar18 = array_slice($scpar, 9, 18, true);
                                  #    ^^^ preserve keys
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the keys ($sid), you need to set the fourth param to true for array_slice, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php